# get current vim mode inside vimscript code

Tags: vimscript, linux

I would like to be able to get the current usual mode of vim inside a vim script (and not only inside the statusline).
I need this functionality to build a vim script linked with ruby script to be able to change keyboard keys colors depend of vim current mode and motion state.
My problem is that vim doesn't know to provide his mode state inside vim script (only inside statusline), or i failed to get it.
I think it should have a point there to make vim better by provide a helpful mode() function who can really provide vim current mode (not only in normal mode and not only for statusline).

This way dev's users would be able without pain to build script to recognize current vim mode and then build interactive script.
Also, i'm now able to get FocusGained (i'm not Windows user, my OS is archlinux and sometimes FreeBSD) with adding ugly/tricky vimscript and i think this point can also be increase for vim source code to be not only for gvim or Windows users.

Try to imagine you want to create a script for color rgb keyboard keys to show currenty mode and aviable keys to hit depend on mode and motion/other state... how to do that if FocusGained and mode() only works for some very limited situations ?

Comment: `mode()` returns 'n', because you **are** in Normal. And you switch there **yourself** in order to execute the script. Simply recall the place where that happened.

Comment: Sorry Matt, you presume something, but you are wrong. The statusline show insert mode, because i'm in insert mode, and mode() return 'n' instead of 'i'.
Look: https://gist.github.com/jerome-diver/b96efb9600bf613aa59683bb2f5f090f

Comment: From `:help mode()`: "This is useful in the 'statusline' option or when used with remote_expr(). In most other places it always returns 'c' or 'n'." The usual way to accomplish this is to set `'statusline'` to include a call to a function that doesn't produce any output but stores the actual mode somewhere (or possibly executes the external command, though you probably don't want to delay writing the status line waiting for an external command to complete...)

Comment: The code in the status line is called by Vim when it thinks it's appropriate. That makes a HUGE difference. For instance, you can catch `autocmd SafeState` and/or `SafeStateAgain` and the `mode()` will return different values. But if you run your script "synchronously", from mapping or such, you can only do this upon switching into normal (like `<CR>` to end cmdline and execute it _in normal mode_).

Comment: `mode()` returns an `i` just fine in insert mode. (E.g., Ctrl-R `=mode()`)

Comment: I'm unable to come up with a scenario where `mode()` returns the incorrect mode. In particular, calling it from a `FocusGained` autocommand seems to work fine for me. Could you be more specific about the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: I also can't figure out what you mean by `Also, i'm now able to get FocusGained (i'm not Windows user, my OS is archlinux and sometimes FreeBSD) with adding ugly/tricky vimscript`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes fibranden, that is why i think that vim, objectively, can be implemented the way mode() ,function can get back what vim script devs users need. Some mode() function more efficient.

Comment: Matt, i think you are starting to understand my question now. I appreciate.
muru, no, before to answer quickly something wrong or deny, try it first. fibranden underestand it perfectly, i think you can do it the same.

Comment: Rich, i copy/paste a gist code, feel free to just open copy/paste and try it to see. The code is the most elaborate test case for show the situation. Devs like to test codes instead of use sentences.
Thank you also to really try to help me and want vim to be better.

Comment: jerome, `InsertEnter` is triggered **before** entering insert mode; `CmdwinEnter` opens a cmd-window in **normal mode**; and `FocusGained` is only guaranteed to work in GVim. So all your problems are due to RTFM.

Comment: Matt, yes sure. So as long as vim devs doesn't find a solution, what users who want to use vimscript can do to get "i" from mode() function when vim is in insert mode ?

Comment: fibranden, your comment on my mind seems to be the best. So for me the next step should be to know "how to set statusline to call function with the result of mode() function to pass explicitely the usual vim mode statement. And hope the next vim version to be better on this point to provide a better mode state information for vimscript users.

Comment: jerome, you keep asking a wrong question and hence you don't get the right answer. The point is that `mode()` is "good" as it returns the true mode. Your problem is that you keep calling it in a wrong time and/or in a wrong way. But there is plenty of ways to do this right: read `:h SafeState`, `:h CursorHold`, `:h timer_start()` etc.

Comment: ok Matt, thank you for your help, i want you to be happy and then: mode() is very very good but when i'm in insert mode, to get current status mode from vimscript, mode() or mode(1) doesn't give me 'i' or 'insert', and then, i have to find an other one tricky way to get the current vim mode from mode(). That's it really, not my fault also, and it is (incredibly) complicate. to just get vim mode status. but yes, fibranden does understand it perfectly and helped me. I will have a look also with SafeState, CursorHold, timer_start by curiosity. Feel free to add a constructive comment.

Comment: Ok, i get positive result from fibranden technic who consist to get correct answer of vim current mode from set statusline to get mode() value to pass to function's argument and store argument in a variable, next step i can get real user vim mode and use it in a vimscript.... complicate but efficient. It should have some other hacks to get the real vim current user mode. thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's tricky and complicated, because Vim is tricky and complicated by design. And I don't say the design is good, but one has to understand it or he'll drop the tool soon. And, by the way, status line update in Vim is rather unreliable; in my experience it only works smooth in Neovim. Perhaps, that's not a big issue given the application's purpose, but, personally, I would never even try to go this way.

Comment: Matt, i don't know, i'm happy with vim (with emacs too), i would like to thinking it will be better soon as long as more users want and devs find some solutions. It seems to not be easy by the way. I will also try by other one way as you suggest. Thank you for share your experience Matt, i appreciate.